# React Router causing AJAX call in Reflux store to fail

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, url-routing, react-router

I have the following AJAX call in a Reflux store:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'submit.php',
  context: this,
  method: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data){...},
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, error){...}
});
```

Here are my routes:

```
let browserHistory = createBrowserHistory();
ReactDOM.render((
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <IndexRoute component={About} />

      <Route path="about" component={About} />
      <Route path="leaderboards" component={LeaderboardPage} />
      <Route path="profile" component={Profile} />
      <Route path="validate/:projectName" component={Validate} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('app'));
```

Whenever the `Validate` component asks its store to make an AJAX request, the request is being made to `validate/submit.php` instead of `submit.php`. What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you supply just a filename to `$.ajax` instead of an absolute path or URL the browser uses it as a relative URL. Since the URL path of the current page is `/validate/foo` (never mind that it's set by `history.pushState`; the browser makes no distinction), it assumes you want to request `submit.php` relative to that path, which is `/validate/submit.php`.

You should always use an absolute path or full URL when making requests in the browser, e.g.:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/submit.php',
  // ...
});
```

Comment: Mmm, indeed, I'll do that in the future, thanks! I recently upgraded from `react-router` v0.13.3 to v1.0.0-rc4. In the old version this code worked fine, the difference being that the old version used HashHistory instead. Would that be the breaking change in the behavior?